# Oracle Protocol violation SQLException

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlexception

I am getting Oracle Protocol Violation SQLException when I am  calling connection.commit().  I have read other post which are saying that it might be due to password is about to expire. But in my case it is not. Also jdbc driver should be fine because for some other engine I do not have such a problem. What else can be problem do you have any idea ?

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:558)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3674)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3680)
 at oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper.commit(OracleConnectionWrapper.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally the issue with the ojdbc7 jar. If the length of clob is 4193 characters, the driver fails to retrieve. Use new OJDBC7 patch jar

Happy Coding ..!!!

Comment: is same issue exist in older version of  jdbc?